# Registering Pre Trained Models from Storage Account Into Azure ML

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-account

**Context:** I have some models in an Azure Storage Account (Data Lake Storage Gen2). I have a workspace in Azure ML. I want to register these models into my Azure ML workspace. I was able to create a Datastore (type: Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2) and point it to my storage account successfully.

**Issue:** When I try to Register the Model from Datastore:
[image: Register From datastore]

My new Datastore is not available in Select Datastore dropdown.
[image]
Only the Datastore that gets created by default workspaceblobstore is available in the dropdown. I changed the default datastore to my new Datastore but it still only shows workspaceblobstore in the dropdown.

**Questions:**

- How do I get my new datastore to show up in the dropdown?
- There are other datastores in the workspace but the dropdown doesn't show any
  of them. Can you please elaborate a little on what's the criteria for datastores to show up in select datastore dropdown?

**Thanks for your valuable inputs. :)**

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 0):

The storage account visibility will differ from different types of application. When the application is normal machine learning application, then the default data store will be blob and we cannot change that. If we need gen2 or gen 1 and other storage accounts, we need to change the type of application like functions and logic apps which relates to machine learning and web apps development.

Check the below screens for further information.

[image]

Created storage account with data lake gen 2 and even mention the type of data store in the above

[image]

[image]

Created a datastore by selecting the type.

[image]

Created a storage account.

[image]

Give all the information.

[image]

Create a container.

[image]

[image]

By default it will be blob storage

[image]

Get the SAS token from the below screen

[image]

[image]

Enen though tried to connect it with other storage type. Default storage will be blob.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps answer the question. You just shared steps on creating a storage account and adding a datastore, but the OP stated they already had all of that ready. They're just having difficulty referencing that datastore when registering their model(s)